# パッケージ単位でのインポート方法について

Tags: python, python3

以下のようなディレクトリ構成

```
model
├── __init__.py
├── supplement.py
├── supplement_name.py
├── supplement_property.py
└── vitamin.py
```

で、`supplement.py`から他のディレクトリ

- supplement_name.py
- supplement_property.py
- vitamin.py

を以下のように**model**パッケージとして呼び出したいと考えています。

```py
from model import Vitamin, SupplementProperty, SupplementName
```

しかし、この呼び出し方だと以下のようなエラーが出てimportに失敗します。

```
> py model/supplement.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model/supplement.py", line 3, in <module>
    from model import Vitamin, SupplementProperty, SupplementName
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model/supplement.py", line 3, in <module>
    from model import Vitamin, SupplementProperty, SupplementName
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'
```

import方法を以下のような方式で行えばエラーは発生しません。

```
from supplement_name import SupplementName
from supplement_property import SupplementProperty
from vitamin import Vitamin
```

supplement.pyの内容は以下のようになっています。

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from model import Vitamin, SupplementProperty, SupplementName
# from supplement_name import SupplementName
# from supplement_property import SupplementProperty
# from vitamin import Vitamin


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Supplement:
    id: str
    name: SupplementName
    prop: SupplementProperty
    vitamin: Vitamin


if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Supplement(
        id='test',
        name=SupplementName(code='test', detail='test-detail'),
        prop=SupplementProperty(price=100, tablet_num=100, manufacture='test-mn'),
        vitamin=Vitamin(va=1000)
    )
    print(s)
```

__init__.pyの内容

```py
from .supplement import Supplement
from .vitamin import Vitamin
from .supplement_property import SupplementProperty
from .supplement_name import SupplementName
```

`python -m model.supplement`と実行した場合、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
/usr/bin/python3.7: Error while finding module specification for 'model.supplement' (ImportError: cannot import name 'Vitamin' from 'model' (/home/tan/repositories/healthcare/backend/model/__init__.py))
```

**model**というパッケージ単位でのimport方法があれば教えて下さい。

Comment: `python -m model.supplement` で発生しているエラー(`cannot import name 'Vitamin' from 'model'`) ですが、`model/__init__.py` に `from .vitamin import Vitamin` という行はありますか？(手元の環境では問題なく実行されます)

Comment: はい、\_\_init\_\_.pyに`from .vitamin import Vitamin`は存在しています。\_\_init\_\_.pyの内容を追記しました。

Comment: ちょっと自信がないのでコメントとして書きますが、`from . import Vitamin, SupplementProperty` ではうまく行きませんか？

Comment: 失敗はしますが、エラーの内容が変わりました。
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: `__init__.py` から `from .supplement import Supplement` を削除して `python -m model.supplement` を実行するとどうなりますか？

Comment: 正常に実行できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

※ 以下、回答ではなく、コメントでのやり取りの補足になります

`__init__.py` の最後に `from .supplement import Supplement` を置いて `python3 -m model.supplement` を実行しますと、

```
from .vitamin import Vitamin
from .supplement_property import SupplementProperty
from .supplement_name import SupplementName
from .supplement import Supplement   ## <--- Here
```

以下の様なワーニングメッセージが表示されます。

```
/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'model.supplement' found in
sys.modules after import of package 'model', but prior to execution of
'model.supplement'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
```

つまり、`double import` になっている事が原因です。

この件に関しては、以下の回答が参考になります。

[Python 3.6 project structure leads to RuntimeWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070583)